# How to parse HK stock exchange Date Table with Chinese Character into Excel using Python?

Tags: python, html, excel, character-encoding

How to parse the HK Stock Exchange date table, (which contains Chinese characters), from [this endpoint](http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/bmn/ebmn_c.htm) into excel using python?

Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/bmn/ebmn_c.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
open('table.csv', 'wb').write(response.content)
read_file = pd.read_csv (r'C:\table.csv')
read_file.to_excel (r'C:\table.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, are you getting errors when running the snippet above?

Comment: The codes seems can only get the heading, but the date in the table is not parsed into file.

Comment: Maybe try and ask your question more around this issue you're describing

Comment: The quotes fails to get the table from ""http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/bmn/ebmn_c.htm" into excel. No data. Only garbage was downloaded. Please advice. Thank you in advance!